# Websphere 8.5.5.2 server not starting when using IBM SDK 1.7.1_64

Tags: websphere-8

I have Websphere 8.5.5.2 server installed. The server is starting fine with SDK 1.6. I have IBM SDK 1.6 and 1.7.1 installed as you can see below:-

```
> managesdk.bat -listAvailable
CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.6_64
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.7.1_64
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.
```

When I change the profile to use SDK 1.7.1_64, the websphere server is not starting. It gives below error:-

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.tmPut(ILjava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry;)I
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1004)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityConfigManagerImpl.getObjectFromRCS(SecurityConfigManagerImpl.java:2502)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityConfigManagerImpl.getObject(SecurityConfigManagerImpl.java:2062)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityConfigManagerImpl.getObjectList(SecurityConfigManagerImpl.java:2296)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityConfigObjectImpl.getObjectList(SecurityConfigObjectImpl.java:134)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.KeyStoreManager.loadKeyStores(KeyStoreManager.java:708)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager.initializeServerSSL(SSLConfigManager.java:235)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.SSLComponentImpl.initialize(SSLComponentImpl.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initWsComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1192)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1099)
...
```

There are no projects added to the server, so there is no code related issue. Why isn't the server starting with SDK 1.7.1?

Comment: This looks like a product issue.  I would open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Check this out: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002#WebSphere%208.5.5%20Java%207.1 and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21692797

The logs which you posted are the Deployment Manager Logs?

Comment: Any follow up on this - did it ever get resolved?

Comment: I am facing the same problem.